# NoSQL for a Rails Engine on MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, nosql, rubygems

I'm writing a Rails engine to sell tickets to events on your own website. I'm implementing discounts for tickets. We're going to have a lot of potential discounts:

- 10% off all tickets
- 10% off a purchase of x tickets or more
- Buy x, get one free
- $5 off a purchase
- $5 off a purchase of x tickets or more
- etc.

I have a discount table, and there are multiple kinds of properties I need to store for each type of discount going on. I think I's like to shy away from STI in general, because of the variety of discounts we have going on and how easy it may be to confuse the data when dealing with similar types of discounts.

I would prefer to have a properties column using hstore in postgresql. But I have to also provide support for MySQL and SQLite. Is there some easy cross-database-compatible way of storing NoSQL-like data in any given SQL database? Should I serialize everything with Ruby? (It won't be often that I'll need to run queries against specific properties in that column.)

Comment: Maybe something like [serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize)?

Comment: I mentioned that, but then doing queries on the table is nearly impossible, as opposed to just "hard" if I did something by hand in MySQL, or totally "easy" with HStore. I don't want to lose out on the benefits Postgres gives for the people that use it.

Answer (score 0):

To support all those DBs you will need to serialise your data as JSON directly, and perhaps build your own tables emulating indexes.

If you could support only one DB, I would use PostgreSQL since it provides some NoSQL features that are useful here, including storing JSON as a data type, with indexing of JSON elements within the column.  You can also store arrays as a data type, again with indexing of array elements, or hashes (hstore feature).

- [JSON features in Postgres](https://lwn.net/Articles/497069/) from LWN
- [Blog about Rails 4](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/a-love-affair-with-postgresql-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) including use of Postgres hstores and arrays.

Rails 3 and Django (pre 1.8) support this sort of advanced feature through gems/packages.

Rails 4 and [Django 1.8+](https://realpython.com/blog/python/fun-with-djangos-new-postgres-features/) support some of these features directly, including [JSON fields](http://orokusaki.posthaven.com/djangos-new-jsonfield-is-awesome) in Django 1.9.